# JS 'click' Event Listener on <select> is taking two clicks?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple filter set on a select tag with three options.  When i change to a new option the list should filter.  This works but i have to select one of the three options and then click the select box again for it to take effect?  Is there an obvious reason for this?

HTML

```
            <select name = "todos" class = "filter-todo">
                <option value = "all">All</option>
                <option value = "completed">Completed</option>
                <option value = "uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

JS

```
const filterTodo = (e) => {                                 //needs fixing(the options need two clicks)
    const todos = todoList.childNodes
    todos.forEach(function(todo){
        switch(e.target.value){
            case "all":
                todo.style.display = "flex"
                break;
            case "completed":
                if (todo.classList.contains('completed')){
                    todo.style.display = "flex"
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = "none"
                }
                break;
            case "uncompleted":
                if (!todo.classList.contains('completed')){
                    todo.style.display = "flex"
                } else 
                    todo.style.display = "none"
                break;
        }
    })
} 

const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo')
filterOption.addEventListener('click', filterTodo)
```

Comment: You must use the "select" event, not "click".

Comment: That doesnt work at all if i change to 'select'?

Comment: ```filterOption.addEventListener('change', filterTodo);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` is the wrong event to subscribe to. It will fire upon any click inside of the DOM tree, including on the `option`s themselves. To avoid this `select` has another event you should subscribe to instead. Just change one line and you're good to go:

```
filterOption.addEventListener('change', filterTodo)
```

This fires when the value changes, so when it's selected option is updated. More information can be found in plenty of places, so for good measure [here is MDN on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).